# Logarithm function from graph (word problem)

Tags: functions, word-problem

I was hoping to find some hint to solve this:

There is an internet company that wants to price their service $30/month, which will include 25GB on their package. After 25GB, the price will increase logarithmically until 60 dollars for 60GB

I know the Y axis would be price and X axis would be the GB..

Two known point is (25, 30) which is starting price and monthly allowance of GB, and (60, 60). There is a logarithmic curve between those two points. How do I find the equation for this? It is supposed to be in the form of f(x) = a + b ln |x|

Comment: You've almost got it.  Just write the equation for the two known values of $(x,y=f(x))$, then solve for $(a,b)$.

Comment: oh wow.. so, say, 30 = a + b ln |25| ??

Comment: @melvin that is for the first "value" of $(x,y)$ (namely the point $(25,30)$).  Do that again for the point $(60,60)$ and you will get another equation very similar but with different numbers.  Thus you will have two equations in two unknowns ($a$ and $b$) which you can solve using your favorite method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a piecewise function **K(u)** where **u** is the data usage in GB such that:

```
         { 25       | u<=25;    }
    K(u)={ 25+f(u)  | 25<u<=60; }
         { 60       | u>60      }
```

Here, f(u) is the function that you need to find; i.e.  **y(x)=a + b *ln*(x)** 
Then you would solve for **b** the following equations:

```
    (1) y1=b*ln(x1)
    (2) y2=b*ln(x2)
```

From there it's just a matter of plugging and chugging to evaluate for **b**.

Comment: Thank you so much! But just to clarify, when it comes to 
(1) y1 = b*ln(x1)
(2)y2 = b*ln(x2)

would it mean the x1, y1 and x2, y2 can use the known coordinate of (25,30) for x1,y1 and (60,60) for x2,y2?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's what it means!

Comment: @nick5435 You really should learn how to [typeset](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) the math correctly. For example, you could have the following:
$$
K(u)=
\begin{cases}
25 & \text{if $u\leq 25$},\\
25+f(u) &\text{if $25<u\leq 60$},\\
60 &\text{if $u>60$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Crash, I will learn such tomorrow. I'm still getting a hang of LaTeX, so I'm just using my patchwork of HTML to supplement for now.

Comment: Hey I was wondering if I did this right.. so I tried it out and did a simultaneous equation with the method you had given me, (60 = b.ln60) - (30 = b.ln25) ---------- (60-30) = (b.ln 60 - b.ln 25) ---------- 30 = b.ln (60/25) ---------- b = 30/(ln2.4) ---------- b = 34.26735727 ---------- so, the equation should be Y = 34.26735727.lnX but when I tested x with 60, it doesn't give 60 like it was supposed to for the known point (60,60) am i doing it wrong?